# How to correct for inperfect 90 degree phase shift before doing IQ demodulation?

Tags: demodulation, phase

I want to sample two signals, S and R and later do IQ demodulation on these.

I am multiplying S with R and I also want to multiply S with a 90 degree phase shifted version of R by shifting the samples in R so I get a 90 degree phase shift.
The problem I encounter with this is that unless I have a sampling rate that is 4*n of the sine signal frequency (where n is an integer) I wont be able to phase shift the R signal by 90 degrees. And this is my case as the sampling rate and the signal frequency are not in this multiple of each other. So let's say I am able to do a 82 degree phase shift. Is it then possible to correct for this somehow for the total number of periods I choose to sample?

Does it at all give any additional information when doing IQ demodulation when I phase shift the reference signal by shifting the samples to get a 90 degree phase shift?

EDIT:
Measuring range is 3k->300k Hz. S is a single frequency sine wave and R a square wave.

Comment: Your best bet is to delay R by a non-integer amount, using a *fractional delay filter*.

Comment: Is "R" a sinusoid or something else?

Comment: You can implement the 90 degree phase shift using a [Hilbert transform filter](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Analytic_Signals_Hilbert_Transform.html), which will work well over a range of frequencies.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: This might work, but it seems like maybe the Hilbert transform which is suggested below is better/easier for my application.

Comment: @JimClay: "R" is a pure one frequency sinusoid.

Comment: @JasonR: The Hilbert transform seems nice, but is it efficient? I am developing without a FPU on a micro controller. It seems like I have to do FFT -> phase shift -> IFFT?